# SSL connection failed because of validation failure

Tags: validation, ssl, cryptography

I am working in establishing a secure communication channel between a java server and a TLS client. During the handshake, all goes well, the client Hello and server Hello messages are correct. Moreover, they both generate the same  master secret for the engaged session. But at the really end of the handshake, server throws an exception telling "Ciphertext sanity check fails".

Client trace

```
0050 - 34 68 ed 2f 6e                                    4h./n

>>> TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
    01
write to 0x1878b98 [0x18891f0] (6 bytes => 6 (0x6))
0000 - 14 03 03 00 01 01                                 ......
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
    14 00 00 0c 14 54 0c 4d c0 22 62 90 c2 92 a1 d1
write to 0x1878b98 [0x18891f0] (45 bytes => 45 (0x2D))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 28 b7 76 bd-36 cd cd eb 8d 9f 34 46   ....(.v.6.....4F
0010 - 25 f7 61 cc cd a3 8e af-6d da 14 60 3c 0f 50 21   %.a.....m..`<.P!
0020 - f4 cc 7a a4 af cf 75 d8-48 54 ee b9 44            ..z...u.HT..D
read from 0x1878b98 [0x187f7e3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02                                    .....
read from 0x1878b98 [0x187f7e8] (2 bytes => 2 (0x2))
0000 - 02 28                                             .(
<<< TLS 1.2 Alert [length 0002], fatal handshake_failure
    02 28
```

Server's side:

```
[Raw read]: length = 5

0000: 14 03 03 00 01                                     ..... 
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
Thread-0, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 28                                     ....(
[Raw read]: length = 40
0000: B7 76 BD 36 CD CD EB 8D   9F 34 46 25 F7 61 CC CD  .v.6.....4F%.a..
0010: A3 8E AF 6D DA 14 60 3C   0F 50 21 F4 CC 7A A4 AF  ...m..`<.P!..z..
0020: CF 75 D8 48 54 EE B9 44                            .u.HT..D
Thread-0, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
Thread-0, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Thread-0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
Thread-0, called closeSocket()
Thread-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: ciphertext sanity check failed
```

What I can not understand is why the server is launching such exception while it succeeds in decrypting the ChangeCipherSpec message sent from the client? What could be the reason for such exception?

N.B: I already check and they both derived the same master key, here it is:

Server's side

```
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 48 B2 6C 02 B1 40 0B D9   6E 14 EB 7A 93 7D 2F 07  H.l..@..n..z../.
0010: 90 CF 1E 5D 65 8A 66 89   54 D4 60 50 BD AC AB 34  ...]e.f.T.`P...4
Server Nonce:
0000: 54 FD 9A E3 BB D4 15 61   A6 0C D3 30 FA 07 0A 16  T......a...0....
0010: 79 A8 79 0B 0A 81 00 95   9C CA C0 7A F1 FF 37 E7  y.y........z..7.
Master Secret:
0000: 39 5B EB 11 66 09 25 B5   6D E4 C7 86 E4 3E 10 BB  9[..f.%.m....>..
0010: B4 F0 D9 B7 BD 7D 8F AD   58 38 31 42 B6 90 53 AD  ........X81B..S.
0020: 54 46 36 DC F5 75 8A 9D   77 58 D5 24 6C 96 90 02  TF6..u..wX.$l...
```

Client's side

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 54FD9AE3A3B3BF807F408FA830641F850702E986C27FC631AF8E8E3097038166
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 395BEB11660925B56DE4C786E43E10BBB4F0D9B7BD7D8FAD58383142B69053AD544636DCF5758A9D7758D5246C969002
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

Comment: The ChangeCipherSpec message isn't encrypted unless there has been a prior successful handshake. Otherwise, encryption starts after it.

Comment: Thanks, for this precision. Therefore, from the client's trace, I can suggest that the client said ChangeCipherSpec which is well received by the server. Next, client sends HandshakeFinished message (from the trace, I can not see he is writing this into the buffer, but let assume it) before sending the encrypted message starting with 16 03 03 00 28. Can you please, confirm me that this is actually what happens?

Comment: The client has sent a `Finished` message, that's the write after the `ChangeCipherSpec.` The `Finished` message is the first encrypted message, and it also contains a MAC over all the previously sent messages, as another MITM defence. It looks like the server is objecting to the `Finished` message. Maybe you *have* an MITM attack.

Comment: MITM is not possible at this time as I am running client and server on the same computer.

Comment: Good. It's curious that the client wrote 45 bytes at once but the server read them as 5 then 40. It looks like the same data on a quick scan, and no reason why it shouldn't be. Did you write the TLS client?

Comment: No I am using openssl as client. I have ran successful handshake in another setting and it appears to be normal that the server divides the stream as 45=05+40. In this particular case, the 45 bytes are divided as follow: the first 5 bytes (16 03 03 00 28) represent header in hex format. It tells the server that it will receive 0x28 (40) bytes of data from the client. Then, the 40 remaining bytes actually corresponds to the encrypted data from the client.

Comment: Found the solution. The problem comes from my openssl client (openssl 1.0.0.f) which can not properly encode/decode using AES256-GCM. When I force the server not to use such cipher, handshake succeeds then they can exchange data in a secure way. :D